# Start SQL replication using differential backup

Tags: sql-server, replication, backup

I need to replicate a few databases but they are too (>100GB) to use snapshot or to copy the full backup on last minute (it take around 5 hrs to copy the full backup across centers).  I'm looking to see if it is possible to first restore on the subscriber the full backup and next day use the differential backup to configure the replication (from backup) is that possible?
What will be the steps?

Comment: Does this mean you've never tested if your backup procedure is working?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible however you need to ensure that no full backup runs in between your last full backup and the current differential backup. If full backup runs then it should be copy only. Whenever you take full backup, the successive differential backup gets linked with that.

Differential backup contains all the changes done from last full backup. So, if you have multiple differential backup after last full backup, you need to consider only the last one and not previous ones.

Below image from [Prashanth Jayaram](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-sql-server-backup-types/) helps in understanding:

[image]